# Why does an unassigned int have a value?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, integer

If i run the following code it shows a long number.

```
int i;    
int *p;    
p= &i;     
cout<<*p;
```

Why does an unassigned int have a value? And what is that value?

Comment: undefined, but most often whatever happens to be there.

Comment: Why introduce `p` into this? You could just as well have posted `int i; cout << i;`.

Answer (score 5):

The value of the pointer `p` is the address of the `int i`. You assigned it with the address-of `&` operator: `p = &i`. The `int i` itself is not initialized also called default initialized. When you dereference your pointer with `*p` you get the value of your uninitialized `int i` which could be anything.

The value of your `int i` is the uninitialized memory interpreted as `int`. Using uninitialized variables is undefined behaviour.

Also you would have the same behaviour without a pointer by simply doing:

```
int i;
cout << i;
```

Comment: More or less correct, but the value of an uninitialized local isn't the residual bits of that memory location - the value is  *indeterminate*. The fact that it's indeterminate is what invokes undefined behavior, as you correctly state at the end. A local variable that's not initialized might as well not exist, as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Thanks for pointing this out. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Though it's also worth noting that if the type is `unsigned char` specifically, it's still indeterminate but it's not necessarily UB to read it.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I think it is always UB in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza For unsigned narrow character types specifically, the spec makes an exception (at 8.5p12) that allows the indeterminate value to be passed around in *some* cases (though it can still invoke UB in others). It even has a code example highlighting this.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Right, but it is still undefined to read the value to print it which is what this question and answer are doing. You are only allowed (simplified) to read the value to discard the result or to copy it to another object, which then also becomes indeterminately valued.

Comment: @hvd True, it's not applicable to the question at hand. I was just mentioning it to make my previous comment a bit more accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Because this is what "undefined behavior" means in C++.

"Undefined behavior" means "anything is possible". This includes:

- You getting some random value for the object. It can be always the same, or different every time you run the code.
- The program crashes.
- Your computer starts playing the latest Justin Bieber video, all by itself, with no way to stop it.
- The universe, as you know it, comes to an end.

etc... That's what "undefined behavior" means.

Comment: While there's UB in the snippet, the OP asked why *the pointer* has a value, not why the pointed object has a value.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: The title and code clarify that he's actually asking about the `int`, and the last sentence was merely poorly worded.

Comment: Can people stop making those lame jokes about UB, please?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you want to buy a land, where you intend to build a house. To buy a land, you contact the local land seller.

[image]

You need to tell him how much units of land you need. In return, he will tell you the location of the land.

**Done - your land is ready for use.**  But did you notice something ? The land seller only told you the coordinates of the land. He didn't say anything about the land. On the land there could be already existing house. There could even be a Hotel, or an Airport. Who knows what is there? If you try to use land, without building your house first, you have no guarantee what will be there. It is your responsibility as a land owner, to build something on top of the land, and use it as appropriate.

C/C++ is the same as the above example. Asking for a `int`, is like asking for a land with size of 8 units. C/C++ will give you the land, telling you its coordinates. It won't tell you what the land contains. You're responsible for using the land to put a house on top of it. If you don't put a house, and try to enter "the house", you might end up in a Airport.  Hope it's clearer now :).

Answer (score 0):

Simply because the memory location where *i* is has **some value** (whatever value it is). As Sam pointed out, it is a good example of undefined (and unwanted) behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Because variables can't be empty.

Every byte of computer memory always contains something.

Computer programs usually don't clean up memory when they done with it (for speed reasons), thus when you leave a variable uninitialized, it will have some random (more or less) value which was left in this place of memory by another program or by our own code.

Usually it is 0 or a value of some other variable that was recently destructed or some internal pointer.

Answer (score -1):

The current contents of the memory location ( in the stack ) of the variable **i**.